# Can I upgrade jQuery 2 in Ember 2.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

I want upgrade jQuery 1.11.3 to jQuery 2.0 inside Emberjs 2.0. Can I use this version without serious problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. I actually use jQuery 2 + Ember 2 in [my portfolio](http://kuzirashi.github.io/). No problems so far.

My working libraries' versions:

> Ember
>   2.1.0 Ember Data
>   2.1.0 jQuery
>   2.1.4

Answer (score 2):

jQuery 2.0's API is compatible with jQuery 1.9's API. You can use 2.0+ anywhere you can use 1.9 as long as you don't need to support IE6-8.

From the [jQuery 2.0 blog post](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/):

> jQuery 1.9 API equivalence: jQuery 2.0 is API-compatible with 1.9, which means that all of the changes documented in the jQuery 1.9 Upgrade Guide have been applied to jQuery 2.0 as well. If you haven’t yet upgraded to jQuery 1.9, you may want to try that first. Be sure to use the jQuery Migrate plugin.

Since Ember's default jQuery version is 1.11.1, you'll be fine using 2.0+ as long as you're only supporting newer browsers.

I've personally been using jQuery 2.0 since Ember 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

*without serious problems?*

That's a case of older IE versions. If you don't consider them then there might not be any big issue. Yet if you feel there is something fishy in this version of jQuery then you can use **migrate** plugin too.

Comment: I run Ember 2.1, so everything before IE9 is ignored by my application.